# Random unicorn timeouts and flapping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, timeout, unicorn

I'm running a pretty high-traffic Rails 3.2 app on Unicorn and Nginx (multiple web nodes), but every once in a while I will see Unicorn workers start timing out and getting sigkilled by the Unicorn master across all nodes. Of course, when a Unicorn worker gets sigkilled by the Unicorn master, a new worker gets forked in its place, but it also just hangs for 60 seconds then times out and gets killed. This basically happens repeatedly until I hard kill all Unicorn masters and workers.

`Unicorn log:`

```
E, [2013-04-18T12:57:50.007623 #14002] ERROR -- : worker=8 PID:14968 timeout (62s > 60s), killing
E, [2013-04-18T12:57:50.108364 #14002] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 14968 SIGKILL (signal 9)> worker=8
I, [2013-04-18T12:57:50.489505 #15726]  INFO -- : worker=8 ready
E, [2013-04-18T12:57:52.175842 #14002] ERROR -- : worker=5 PID:15033 timeout (61s > 60s), killing
E, [2013-04-18T12:57:52.276586 #14002] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 15033 SIGKILL (signal 9)> worker=5
I, [2013-04-18T12:57:52.653069 #15782]  INFO -- : worker=5 ready
E, [2013-04-18T12:57:56.340290 #14002] ERROR -- : worker=3 PID:15074 timeout (61s > 60s), killing
E, [2013-04-18T12:57:56.440993 #14002] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 15074 SIGKILL (signal 9)> worker=3
I, [2013-04-18T12:57:56.809730 #15832]  INFO -- : worker=3 ready
E, [2013-04-18T12:57:57.504142 #14002] ERROR -- : worker=7 PID:15087 timeout (61s > 60s), killing
E, [2013-04-18T12:57:57.604886 #14002] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 15087 SIGKILL (signal 9)> worker=7
I, [2013-04-18T12:57:57.983581 #15845]  INFO -- : worker=7 ready
E, [2013-04-18T12:57:59.669664 #14002] ERROR -- : worker=4 PID:15108 timeout (61s > 60s), killing
E, [2013-04-18T12:57:59.770427 #14002] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 15108 SIGKILL (signal 9)> worker=4
I, [2013-04-18T12:58:00.155461 #15879]  INFO -- : worker=4 ready
E, [2013-04-18T12:58:06.839906 #14002] ERROR -- : worker=9 PID:15192 timeout (61s > 60s), killing
E, [2013-04-18T12:58:06.940829 #14002] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 15192 SIGKILL (signal 9)> worker=9
I, [2013-04-18T12:58:07.302766 #15956]  INFO -- : worker=9 ready
E, [2013-04-18T12:58:08.003330 #14002] ERROR -- : worker=6 PID:15213 timeout (61s > 60s), killing
E, [2013-04-18T12:58:08.104006 #14002] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 15213 SIGKILL (signal 9)> worker=6
I, [2013-04-18T12:58:08.466790 #15973]  INFO -- : worker=6 ready
```

Monitoring systems show that external services (Postgres database, Memcached, Redis) are all responding properly and without latency issues.

Here are some outputs that may be of value:

During these outages I notice a huge backlog of attempted connections to the Unicorn socket. When the site isn't down, usually the following command returns one or two lines only.

`netstat | grep unic`

```
....
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        /tmp/unicorn.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        /tmp/unicorn.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        /tmp/unicorn.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        /tmp/unicorn.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING    0        /tmp/unicorn.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     7768134  /tmp/unicorn.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     7767311  /tmp/unicorn.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     7766999  /tmp/unicorn.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     7767309  /tmp/unicorn.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     7766941  /tmp/unicorn.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     7767287  /tmp/unicorn.sock
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     7766225  /tmp/unicorn.sock
```

Anyone have an idea what might be causing this? This happens across multiple servers, all at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

DDOS? Before exploring the application level I would make sure you know what happens at network level. How many connections do you have when it works? How many when it does not? From what IPs? etc.